# Разница между переводом reference и referenced

Tags: перевод, семантика

Пытаюсь перевести `referenced document`.
Сколько не искал в интернете и не вбивал в переводчик различные производные слова `reference`, результаты всегда выходят разные.
Как я понимаю `reference document` и `referenced document` имеют разный семантический смысл (наверное как и перевод). Помогите разобраться с этим.

Comment: I guess you posted your quesiton on a wrong communitu of SE.  If you use Russian language to ask question about Russian language, you should ask it here https://rus.stackexchange.com/ This community is for asking questions about Russian language using English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю

**`reference document`** - это документ, на содержание которого следует ориентироваться при выполнении каких-л. действий, **справочный документ**

**`referenced document`** - документ, упомянутый в тексте (устном или письменном), к которому даётся отсылка

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95009/discussion-on-answer-by-------reference--referen).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @MaximPro конечно, вам спасибо за оценку